# Preposition for “Lauschen”

Tags: grammar, word-usage, etymology

I’m trying to find out why English uses *to* with *to listen* as in *I listen to [something.]*  The word *to listen* is cognate to the modern German word *lauschen.*

I know that to say *I listen to [something]* in German one can use *zuhören* or *anhören*, which have the prepositions *zu* and *an.* Seems similar to English in that a direction for attention is required.

My questions:

1) Can lauschen take a preposition? I’m not a native speaker (I grew up in Germany and used to speak fluently but that was years ago). It seems like one could say *anlauschen* or *zulauschen.* but I was not able to find that usage online and none of the examples for lauschen used *an* or *zu* in the sentences.

2) If *lauschen* doesn’t currently take a preposition, did it, at one time?

3) My German dictionary says that *lauschen* means to pay close attention to something in a listening way, but many of the examples I found of its usage imply that *eavesdropping* is the best way to view this word. Is this true? Did the meaning of the word change over time?

Answer (score 6):

**Lauschen** means *listen silently and attentively*.

Without preposition it may just mean listen, often with enjoyment. The object or person you are listening to is given in dative. This *may* also explain your *to* in English — the target (typically dative in German) is translated as *to [target]* in English.

> der Musik lauschen
>   dem Vogelgesang lauschen

It indicates stealth if you say *belauschen* instead, which requires an object in accusative, or if you omit the object (must be infered from the context).

> den Nachbarn belauschen
>   an der Tür lauschen

Comment: Ah, that makes sense ;)

Answer (score 5):

According to [Grimm’s Wörterbuch, *lauschen* in the sense of *listening to* has at earlier stages of German allowed certain prepositions (6.c)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL02370#XGL02370). Examples Grimm gives:

> lauschte ich oft von des vaters lippen *auf* die thaten der edlen Griechen

With *auf*.

> ach tausendmal wirst du (sonne) meerunter sinken,
>   eh dieses auge wieder sich berauscht
>   von seligkeit, in seinem (des freundes) lächelwinken,
>   wenn er auf lieder lauscht!

Again with *auf*.

In modern German, I agree the dative direct argument is the standard usage, followed by the intransitive usage.

Note, your question 1, about *an-* and *zulauschen* refers to prefixes, not prepositions. There is *belauschen*: that is, if you add the prefix *be-* to *lauschen*, it requires an accusative argument referring to somebody who produces sound, no longer a Dative argument referring to sounds.
This *belauschen* is also the best translation of *eavesdropping*. *Lauschen* without the prefix just means *listening*, and would typically refer to music.